# Equivalence of Conditions for an Eigenvalue to Exist

Tags: linear-algebra

I've seen two different conditions for which $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of linear transformation $f$:

1. $\det(f-\lambda I)=0$
2. $f-\lambda I$ is not injective

These conditions seem pretty different.  How are they equivalent?

Comment: Condition 2 should read $f-\lambda I$ is **not** injective.

Comment: oops, yeah.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a linear transformation $g:V \to V$ (over a finite dimensional vector-space) is either invertible (bijective) or is neither injective nor surjective.

The transformation $g$ is neither injective nor surjective if and only if $\det(g) = 0$.  This is usually stated in the following equivalent manner:

> A linear transformation $g:V \to V$ (over a finite dimensional vector-space) is invertible if and only if $\det(g) \neq 0$.

Setting $g = f - \lambda I$ allows you to note the equivalence of the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, det(f−λI)=0 iff f−λI is singular iff Ker(f−λI) is not {0} iff there exists a non-zero x, such that (f−λI)x = 0 iff f−λI is non-injective. For the second equivalence, one uses the rank-nullity theorem: rank(f) + nullity(f) = n.